# Determining if a homomorphism is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inverse, proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, where $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the set of linear operators mapping a vector space $V$ to itself, and let $U$ be an isomorphism from $V$ to another vector space $W$.  We claim that $T \mapsto UTU^{-1}$ determines an isomorphism from $\mathcal{L}(V)$ to $\mathcal{L}(W)$.  I was wondering if this proof of this claim is valid:

Firstly, we know that $UTU^{-1}$ is linear, since a composition of homomorphisms is a homomorphism.  As for whether this is an isomorphism, we know that an isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism.  Now, a map $f$ is bijective if and only if it's invertible - that is to say $f^{-1}$ exists - and composition $f^{-1} \circ f$ is the identity map on the domain of $f$.  So since $U$ is an isomorphism, we guess that $U^{-1}(x)U$ is the inverse of $U(x)U^{-1}$ and try to show this; sure enough, $U^{-1}(UTU^{-1})U$ can be manipulated under associativity of homomorphic composition to show that $(U^{-1}U)T(U^{-1}U) = Id(T(Id(V)) = T$.

Is this sound?  I appreciate insightful commenters offering nice alternative approaches and such - and feel free to do so - but I hope to get some feedback on whether or not my specific approach given here is a valid one.

Comment: Yes, you have proved that $f$ is injective. You also need to prove that $f\circ f^{-1} = id$ to show it is surjective.

Comment: You also have to show that it's a homomorphism from $\mathcal L(V)$ to $\mathcal L(W)$, whatever that means.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f\colon \mathcal L(V)\mapsto \mathcal L(W)$ by $f(T)=UTU^{-1}$.  It's easy to show that $f$ is a linear map; just verify $f(S+T)=f(S)+f(T)$ and $f(\lambda T)=\lambda f(T)$ 
for all $S,T\in\mathcal L(V)$ and any scalar $\lambda$.  Now 
$$f(T)=\mathrm{id}_W\iff UTU^{-1}=\mathrm{id}_W\iff T=U^{-1}\mathrm{id}_WU=\mathrm{id}_V,$$
hence $\ker(f)=\mathrm{id}_V$, so $f$ is an isomorphism between $\mathcal L(V)$ and $\mathcal L(W)$.

Clarification: you don't have to show that $U^{-1}TU$ is a linear map (from $V$ to $W$), but that $f$ is a linear map from $\mathcal L(V)$ to $\mathcal L(W)$, that is $f\in\mathrm{Hom}\bigl(\mathcal L(V),\mathcal L(W)\bigr)$.